# How to fix Certbot's incomplete chain on CentOS 7?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, centos7, certbot

I'm using Certbot on CentOs 7 to generate certificates, but my SSL test at https://www.ssllabs.com shows an additional, invalid self-signed certificate causing chain issues and dropping my rating to a B.

I tried commenting out the reference to this certificate, but the httpd service fails to restart if I do and there's no error message provided in the journal:

```
#SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
#SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

How can I fix this chain issue? Can I remove this self-signed cert somehow?

### Edit

Okay, it sounds like I've misunderstood what is causing the chain issue and it's not the local certificate - it's the "extra download" at step 2 in the certification path with the R3 issuer. Certbot doesn't seem to be generating a certificate with a complete chain?

[image: Incomplete chain]

Comment: This *is* your certificate. You need to get one that is signed by a CA. This isn't.

Comment: @user207421 Isn't the certbot created certificate my certificate now? It's listed as certificate #1 with certificate #2 being this self-signed one.

Comment: For questions like yours, you need to provide exact details on the certificate and certificate chain. Tools like **openssl** can provide the required details. Lets Encrypt does not provide self-signed certificates, so you have an error someplace. Where - that is in the details.

Comment: The CertBot-created certificate is your certificate if you placed it in ` /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` and its key in `/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key`, and not otherwise. I don't understand why you thought commenting out those lines would help unless you suspected the self-signed certificate was in there: but it will only make things worse if your server requires a certifcate and private key, as it appears to.

Answer (score 0):

[Certbot creates *several* files](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates) such that "cert.pem contains the server certificate by itself, and chain.pem contains the additional intermediate certificate or certificates" while "fullchain.pem [contains] ... the server certificate ... followed by any intermediates".

**If you want the full chain (in Apache httpd), use the file named fullchain.**

Note LE is currently providing by default a chain that bridges to the DST root which expired last week because this allows old Android clients to work -- but it causes some old OpenSSL clients to fail; there are numerous Qs about this here and on other Stacks. You may wish to choose the 'ISRG' chain instead; see e.g. [The SSL connection could not be established: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395823/the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-system-security-authentication-auth) .

Comment: My httpd config is already using the fulchain.pem as the SSLCertificateFile. Any idea why I might still be getting this "Extra download" step in my chain? This issue does seem to coincide with the recent expiration.

Comment: Nof if your file is correct and you are using httpd 2.4.8 up. Check `awk -vcmd='openssl x509 -noout -subject' '{print|cmd}/-----END/{close(cmd)}' fileyouuse.pem` -- the second output line should be `subject=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3`.

Answer (score 0):

My ignorance on certificates aside, I believe the issue I'm experience is best described here: https://blog.devgenius.io/lets-encrypt-change-affects-openssl-1-0-x-and-centos-7-49bd66016af3

Since I'm running CentOs 7, I believe I need to use all three of these apache settings to include the proper intermediate certificates:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{cert-name}/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{cert-name}/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{cert-name}/privkey.pem
```